# Help with a complex number equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been trying to solve the following equation:

$z^2z^*−3z|z|+2z=0$

(z* is the conjugate of z)

I tried as following:

$z^2z^*−3z|z|+2z=0$

$z|z|^2−3z|z|+2z=0$

$z(|z|^2−3|z|+2)=0$

And from here I dont really know what I got to do (?). Also I tried to use Euler's formula and to substitute z with x+yi, but got stuck in the same way.

Comment: so either $z$ is identically zero or $|z|$ satisfies the above quadratic, constrain being $|z|$ now has to be positive

Comment: "Also I tried to use Euler's formula and to substitute z with x+yi, but got stuck in the same way."  Your analytical approach is very good, and your instincts about considering the substitutions of $z = (x + iy)$ or (perhaps) $z = re^{i\theta}$ is also good.  As has been indicated by the other responses, your only stumble was not realizing that if $z$ does not happen to equal $[(0) + i(0)]$, then you can divide by $z$ to obtain the quadratic in $|z|$.

Comment: The last equation is $\,z(|z|-1)(|z|-2)=0\,$, and a product is $0$ iff one of the factors is $0$.